# What does "acquaintance" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2 (2011)*, Griphook speaking to Harry Potter about Gryffindor:

> Griphook: Only a goblin would recognize that this is the true sword of
> Gryffindor.
>
> Hermoine: Who is the **acquaintance**?
>
> Griphook: A Hogwarts professor. As I understand it, he's now
> headmaster.

What does "acquaintance" mean in this context?

Comment: Acquaintance is someone who knows about the thing in question. Here, the sword of Gryffindor.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Can't you convert that into answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it sounds weird.  What I think happened was that the original script had a line that was something like

> GRIPHOOK:  The sword was placed in the vault by an acquaintance.

This line was cut from the final movie, but it would explain why Herminone asks "who was the acquaintance?"

See this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/57urd3/a_question_about_something_in_part_2_that_always/)

Acquaintance means just "somebody we know"  and is therefore almost meaningless.  It is typical of goblins not to keep secrets and not give any information away. Griphook would use "an acquaintance" to avoid giving away any details unless directly asked.